# JS: Change class of div while typing in textarea and after some time of not-typing

Tags: javascript, css, keyboard-events

I have a textarea and send button on my webpage.

How can I change the style of the send button (to a particular CSS class) while I'm typing and then after some time of not-typing to another CSS class.

Also, when the message is deleted, the style of the send button must change back to the original CSS class.

Here is the code I tried:

```js
function isTyping(val) {
  if (val == 'true') {
    document.getElementsByClassName('send')[0].innerHTML = "Class1";
  } else {
     document.getElementsByClassName('send')[0].innerHTML = "Class2";
   
  }
}
```

```css
.type-message:focus + .send {
  background-color: red;
}

.class1 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.class2 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="type-message" onkeypress="isTyping('true'); timer=5;" onkeyup="isTyping('false')" name="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">
</textarea>

<div class="send">Class2</div>
```

But it doesn't works. What is wrong?

Comment: Is this what u need https://jsfiddle.net/2k6pzy2y/7/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

`Run CODE snippet` below & type as the textarea appears.

See if this is what you wanted to do:

```js
var delay = 3000; // that's 3 seconds of not typing
var timer = null;
function isTyping() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  var value = document.getElementById('text').value;
  if( value ) {
    document.getElementById('send').innerHTML = "Typing";
    document.getElementById("send").className = "typing";
    timer = setTimeout(notTyping, delay); 
  }
  else {
    notTyping();
  }
}

function notTyping() {
  document.getElementById('send').innerHTML = "Not Typing";
  document.getElementById("send").className = "not-typing";
}
```

```css
#send {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
.not-typing {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.typing {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="type-message" oninput="isTyping()" id="text" name="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
<div id="send" class="not-typing">Not Typing</div>
```

## Problem in your CODE:

The reason your CODE doesn't work is because:

> You changed class on the event `onkeypress` & then immediately on the event `onkeyup`.

`onkeypress` means as you press any key & `onkeyup` means when you release the same key. So as you typed `onkeypress`, `onkeyup`, `onkeypress`, `onkeyup` ...  kept on happening and class kept on changing.

## Instead what I did was:

> 1. Used only one `oninput` event - that detects any change in input.
> 2. Inside event handler used a timer using `setTimeout` function. This only fires after 3 seconds of inactivity or if the `textarea` is empty.